# ITC.app.preReleaseBuild.errors.invalidBinary App Store

Tags: xcode, build, app-store

I uploaded many builds to App Store, but facing two issues.

```
1. Build is invalid
2. ITC.app.preReleaseBuild.errors.invalidBinary
```

[image]

What are errors are these. As apple is not giving any more instructions, where exactly issue is.

I am beta reports active = 1

[image]

Kindly help

Thanks

Comment: Same here. i had many problems with this reports active = true stuff .
I did eveything suggested but did not work. Regenarating profile not working. Even deleting and recreating not working.
İ eventually deleted app and created an app2. Now it says TC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.invalidBinary for the app2. ANy luck solving that

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Check your email. Apple sends an email with exact problem.

In my case, one of my SDK was using `iPhoneSimulator` instead of `iPhoneOS` for `CFBundleSupportedPlatforms` key in its `info.plist` file.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be solved by setting app icons' `alpha channel` to `NO`.
And if you have any files related with `TestFlight` just delete them all.

If this does not help just send request to apple support.